# Preloader image animation not centering

Tags: css, html

My preloader image does not center inside the circle and on small screen the perloader is not center at all. I have tried re-calculating auto margins nothing seems to work. how can I get the image to stay inside without spinning with the circle and center the preloader all together.

```css
#load_cover {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
 z-index: 10000;
}
.loaderInner {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin: -50px 0px 0px -50px;
}
.logo {
 position: absolute;
 background-image: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=40%C3%9745&w=40&h=45");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin: -50px 0px 0px -50px; 
}
.loader {
 border: 4px solid #838383;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border-top: 4px solid #dddddd;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 -webkit-animation: spin 0.6s linear infinite;
 animation: spin 0.6s linear infinite;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px #999;
 filter: blur(0.7px);
}
 @-webkit-keyframes spin {
 0% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
 100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
 @keyframes spin {
 0% {
transform: rotate(0deg);
}
 100% {
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
```

```html
<div id="load_cover">
  <div class="loaderInner">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your negative margins should be half the height and width. Currently your width and height are `60px`, and your negative margins are `-50px`. They should be `-30px`. Also, your spinner has *no* negative margin, meaning you're aligning it's top-left corner to the center, instead of center-to-center. But my real suggestion: Drop absolute positioning and fussing with margins: **use flexbox**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

I took the `.logo` out and placed the image as the background of `.loaderInner` and then you position the image center.

```css
#load_cover {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
 z-index: 10000;
}
.loaderInner {
background-image: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=40%C3%9745&w=40&h=45");
background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 /*margin: -50px 0px 0px -50px;*/
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loader {
 border: 4px solid #838383;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border-top: 4px solid #dddddd;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 -webkit-animation: spin 0.6s linear infinite;
 animation: spin 0.6s linear infinite;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px #999;
 filter: blur(0.7px);
}
 @-webkit-keyframes spin {
 0% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
 100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
 @keyframes spin {
 0% {
transform: rotate(0deg);
}
 100% {
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
```

```html
<div id="load_cover">
  <div class="loaderInner">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```